# Optimal utilities under Diamond & Dybvig model (1983)

Tags: banking

In Diamond and Dybvig's model on deposit contracts and bank runs (1983), the authors derive the optimal utility $\bar{u}$ under no liquidity insurance as:
$$\bar{u}=tu(1)+(1-t)\rho u(R)$$
where $u:\mathbb{R}_+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is the utility function; $t\in[0,1]$ the proportion of consumers which suffer a liquidity shock (type-1) and need to retrieve their investment in the first period; $R>1$ the long-term return from investment if the consumer keeps it until the second period (type-2); and $\rho\in(R^{-1},1]$ a discount factor.

On the other hand, they also derive the optimality condition in the case where a consumer's type is revealed in period 1 - alternatively, using the vocabulary from Tirole (2006), consumers pool their resources at time-zero in a mutual fund:
$$u^\prime(c_1^{1\star})=\beta Ru^\prime(c_2^{2\star})$$
where $c_T^{i\star}$ is the optimal consumption from a consumer of type $i$ in period $T$. The optimal utility under the mutual fund case is:
$$u^\star=tu(c_1^{1\star})+(1-t)\rho u(c_2^{2\star})$$

**Can we establish any relationship (equality or inequality) between the autarky optimum $\bar{u}$ and the mutual fund one $u^\star$? Which additional assumptions would be needed to do so?**